# Target animation speed using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a way to target animation duration of css using jquery?

```css
.hvr-pulse-grow:hover, .hvr-pulse-grow:focus, .hvr-pulse-grow:active {
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-pulse-grow;
  animation-name: hvr-pulse-grow;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-duration: 0.1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you looking to change the value in the CSS or just the value for an element? You can us `.css()` to change the value. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `css()` method to amend the setting of a CSS rule for a given element. In your case it would look something like this:

```
$('.hvr-pule-grow').css('animation-duration', '1s'); // change value argument as required.
```

It's worth noting two additional points. Firstly `animation` rules are now very [well supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=animation). You don't need to use the `-webkit` prefixes on them.

Secondly, it would better practice, if possible, to set the duration using a class and apply that to the element when required. This maintains the separation of concerns between the JS logic and the UI.

```css
.hvr-pulse-grow:hover, 
.hvr-pulse-grow:focus, 
.hvr-pulse-grow:active {
  /* use shorthand rule */
  animation: hvr-pulse-grow 0.1s linear infinite alternate;
}

.hvr-pule-grow.slow {
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
```